# Boundedness of uniform metric

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about the proof I am looking at. The question is as following:

> Let $\mathbf{w}_i=(0, 0, \cdots 0, i, i, i, \cdots)\in \mathbb{R}^\omega$(where there are $i-1$ zeros). Does this sequence converge in uniform topology?

and a part of the proof goes like this:

> ... For the uniform topology, note
> that, given $i ≥ 1$, $\bar{\rho}(\mathbf{w}_i, \mathbf{0})>1$, so $\mathbf{w}_i \notin B_{\bar{\rho}}(\mathbf{0}, 1)$ for all $i$... and so the sequence does not converge in uniform topology of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

My question is, how can $\bar{\rho}(\mathbf{w}_i, \mathbf{0})>1$ happen? The uniform metric I learned is defined as $$\bar{\rho}(\mathbf{x, y})=\sup\{\bar{d}(x_\alpha, y_\alpha) |\alpha \in J\}$$
where $J$ is the index set(in this case, $\mathbb{N}$), and $\bar{d}$ is the standard bounded metric so it is always less than or equal to $1$. Then, the supremum also must be less than or equal to $1$. So, $\bar{\rho}(\mathbf{a, b})\leq 1$ for any two points. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $\bar{\rho}(\mathbf{w}_i, \mathbf{0})=1$ for all $i$ so the sequence does not converge in unfrom metric.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the comment. So it is a error, right? Am I correct about the fact that uniform metric must always be less than or equal to $1$? I get that the sequence does not converge in uniform metric.